# Do I need to add * to listen :80/Listen []:80 for ipv4 and ipv6 WAMP virtual host setup

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost, wampserver

So here is the deal. I'm trying to setup Virtual host with my WAMP.

The instructions I found online tell me to set `Listen :80 to Listen *:80` .

But when I check my httpd.conf file I only see

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

I have no idea what `0.0.0.0 and [::0]` mean.

So my question is do they mean the same as * ? Or should i change

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
```

to

```
Listen 0.0.0.0*:80
Listen [::0]*:80
```

or add below those `Listen *:80`?

Or do I not need to add it at all..?

Thanks in advance!

update: I guess `0.0.0.0:80` is ipv4 and `[::0]:80` is ipv6

But I still have no idea if I need to add `Listen *:80` and/or `Listen [*]:80` or something similar...

any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks again!

Comment: Listen Directive tells you on which IP and Port Address your apache will listen to. So just keep it as `Listen *:80`.

Comment: @Siddharthsharma but it isn't Listen *:80

Comment: * means for all IP address. So you can specify `Listen *:80` or if you know the IP address you can specify IP address also. But it is better to use * instead.

Comment: @Siddharthsharma are you saying I add Listen *:80 below? Because 'Listen :80' does not exist in my file exactly as typed.

Comment: if it is not preset than yes you have to put this line in your configuration file.

Comment: @Siddharthsharma okay. That covers ipv4 . But how would I write it for ipv6...?

Comment: You really need ipv6?? IPv4 will be just fine I think

Comment: @Siddharthsharma it also has ipv6 in the file. and ipv6 is more common now adays. I'd rather have it and be better safe than sorry.

Comment: If you want to add ipv6 than you can do this by `Listen [your ipv6 address]:80` and for all you can use `Listen [::]:80`. This is the configuration, but this will also result in overlapping of address in many cases. So you have to check whether it works for you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what you found online, but here is the official instructions.

If you are using WAMPServer pre V3 :

[WAMPServer Forum: THE NEED for VIRTUAL HOSTS](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757)

If you are using WAMPServer V3, the process has been made simpler and there is now a web page to do almost all of it for you

[WAMPServer Forum: WAMPServer 3 All you need to know](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)

The *:80 is used on the Virtual Host definition and not on the `Listen` directives in `httpd.conf`

The `*` means listen on any ip address, and is simpler than specifying your actual IP Address. As most Windows PC's have only one IP address i.e. only one network card there is no need t be specific with the ip address.

Comment: Can't really beat official instructions. But it doesn't really answer my question. Must I define my ip address:80 (or *:80) or does 0.0.0.0 and [::0] automatically define my ip address for that...? Maybe I'm over thinking this lol. sorry if i am.

Comment: Use `*:80` in the Virtual Host definitions `*` means ALL/ANY ip address.

Comment: Dont mess with the default definition in `httpd.conf` set it back to `Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80`

Comment: I didn't mess with anything. But sounds like I just need to add the Listen *:80 thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to httpd.conf and do the next

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
#Listen 0.0.0.0:80
#Listen [::0]:80
```

and where you find

`ServerName localhost:80`

write

```
ServerName localhost:8080
```

That way I resolved my problem with apache service.